# Check if an object has a property with a specific value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm displaying data from an array of objects but I want to filter the results so that I display only the `name`s of those objects that have a `winner` property with a value of `1`.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var json = [
        {"name":"Name 1","winner":"1"},
        {"name":"Name 2","winner":"0"},
        {"name":"Name 3","winner":"1"},
        {"name":"Name 4","winner":"1"},
        {"name":"Name 5","winner":"0"},
    ];

    var li;
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        li = $('<li/>');
        li.append(json[i].name);
    $('#feed').append(li);
    }
});
</script>
```

HTML should be like this (showing only results when winner is true, `winner`=`1`)

```
<ul id="feed" >
    <li>Name 1</li>
    <li>Name 3</li>
    <li>Name 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is that really a `<font>` tag ?

Comment: That's not JSON: http://json.org/

Comment: with the exception of the comma after the last object, yes it is.

Comment: @Brad.Smith - It certainly isn't, it's a javascript object, but in this case it doesn't really matter.

Comment: @adeneo forgot to delete that. been playing with different things and using CSS now. thanks 4 catching that.

Comment: Try to avoid using <font /> tag. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font

Comment: If you parse a JSON string, which is what you're goign to do to work with the data, var json is what you're going to get . It seems like you're arguing semantics.

Comment: @Brad.Smith: Semantics and using the right terminology are very important. Otherwise, how should we be able to communicate? The problem has nothing to do with JSON, it's a pure JS problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a condition in the loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    if (json[i].winner === "1") {

        $('<li />', {text : json[i].name}).appendTo('#feed');

    }
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7M5LP/)

Answer (score 4):

You may try using an `if` statement:

```
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    if (json[i].winner === '1') {
        li = $('<li/>');
        li.append("<font size='+1'>" + json[i].name + "</font>");
        $('#feed').append(li);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to add an if statement to check if winner is equal to 1:

```
var json = [
        {"name":"Name 1","winner":"1"},
        {"name":"Name 2","winner":"0"},
        {"name":"Name 3","winner":"1"},
        {"name":"Name 4","winner":"1"},
        {"name":"Name 5","winner":"0"},
    ];

    var li;
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    if(json[i].winner == "1"){ //add this
        li = $('<li/>');
        li.append("<font size='+1'>" + json[i].name + "</font>");
    $('#feed').append(li);
    }
 }
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bTS7m/4/)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
    var ul = $('ul#feed');
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        if (json[i].winner == 1) {
            ul.append("<li>" + json[i].name + "</li>");
        }
    }
```

[Working fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/umayr/Gu57k/)